# How to download a very large video file instead of playing in browser with PHP

Tags: php, download, large-files

I have created a movie which I have saved as an MP4 file and uploaded to my server. The file is 4.6 GB.  When I have tried to send a link to my family, the video tries to play in their browser.

What I want to do is have them click a link and the file downloads to their computer instead. I have searched endlessly for solutions, but they all keep failing, probably due to the size of the file.

Is anyone able to help with a PHP script that will allow the downloading of such a large file?

Thanks

Comment: Browsers by default try to play media files, but to your family members, instead of left clicking the link, they can right click and click "Save as..." from the menu: a pop-up will appear asking them where to store the file in their computer. You can also zip the file in the server, and then it won't auto-play (and they can just unzip it after download). For such a big files, it's actually better to use a browser plugin for managing the download, such as [downthemall](http://www.downthemall.net/).

Comment: Now to your real PHP question: you may find a way to partition the file in several different files (e.g.: _mov.r00_) and provide a page with several different links generated in PHP for each part. Once they download all parts, they just have to open the index file and extract the big movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to press **Ctrl+S**, select **File>Save** or do **right click + Save as** in the browser when the file starts to load - this will open the **Save File** dialog.

In case you want to return this file from PHP, you can do that with following script:

```
<?php
$file = 'video.mp4';

if (file_exists($file)) {
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  readfile($file);
  exit;
```

}

Comment: Wow, that is so much shorter than every other script i have tried and failed at.  Thanks.  I prefer the php script over the keyboard shortcuts. A couple of the people I will be sending this to are elderly, so the easier it is for them, the better. Thanks again.